# Django Haystack Search Results Filter Based on SITE_ID?

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack

How to filter search results based on settings.SITE_ID?

I'm having problems with Haystack search results based on SITE_ID. We have multiple websites using one DB that stores everything and the data is displayed based on SITE_ID using Django's site framework.

Using Haystack/Woosh for search, the results are not filtered based on SITE_ID unless we create an index containing the SITE_ID filter (see below), however that will only index values for one website. Without it, it will index all DB values and also return unfiltered data on all websites.

Note: `city_id` has the same values as `site_id` and we can you either.

```
 class SiteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
      text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
      name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name', boost=1.5)
      keywords = indexes.CharField(model_attr='keywords')
      about = indexes.CharField(model_attr='about', boost=0.5)
      city_id = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='city_id')

      content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name')

      def get_model(self):
          return Business

 def index_queryset(self, using=None):
     return self.get_model().objects.filter(city_id=settings.SITE_ID)
```

Comment: Why does it only index results for one website? It seems to me everything's there (the field, the indexing and the filtering) except why it's not doing all sites. How would Haystack/Woosh learn what all sites are? Can you influence that by querying `Site.objects.all()` and feeding it into the indexing process?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! When I index everything, all results, unfiltered by `SITE_ID` are displayed on all websites. Unless there is a way to filter the full indexed results in the template or through some custom view etc. Ayy ideas?

Comment: It could be that, in the template, you're still querying for all objects, not the site specific ones. So it could also be that you're doing everything right, except you're not filtering for the site. Are you always calling `index_queryset`?